# Test connection failed in Informatica Developer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am working with Informatica Developer - Power-Center. I have it installed on 2 computers: my local PC and the MS Server where the Informatica Server is also installed.

I defined a new connection and tested it by clicking Test Connection. On my PC the test works  fine but when I test the connection on the server the test fails with the following error: "[REL_10611] Error returned during ODBC access. ErrorCode=[-1]. Reason=[[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified]."

Another strange thing is that the mapping that includes a relational data object that uses this connection works even on the server and adds row to the DB.
Does anybody know why this could be happening? Is this a bug in the Informatica Developer?

Comment: What tool is Informatica Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the ODBC data source on the server?  The data source needs to be created on both your local PC and on the server.  When using the Developer Tool (and the Power Center client tools for that matter), some operations are executed from your local workstation and some are executed on the Data Integration Service (DIS).

Comment: For sure, I created an ODBC data source also on the server, and even so I still get this error.

Comment: have you tested that ODBC connection from MS server after creation? Also the name of ODBC conneciton and name in Infa developer should be same. Secondly i hope the user running informatica has access to that ODBC connection and related files?